# Turning a list into variables in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I use .readlines(), it gives me a list, can I separate this list into individual variables?

Many thanks if you can help me!

Comment: You can just iterate over a list

Comment: Put the questions and answers in a `dict` and save it using [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: Did you even bother to put that exact question into a google search?

Comment: I think this question is more about how to assign a variable in Python, or how you iterate over a list.

Answer (score 2):

Use a context manager:

```
with open(myfile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

Not sure how your file is formatted, but if it is in the form of:

```
Question
Answer
Question
Answer
.
.
.
Question N
Answer N
```

You can call `enumerate()` over a generator within the context manager and go to specific lines. For example, if you know the line number or perhaps build a dictionary of Q&A for even lines:

```
with open(myfile, 'r') as f:
    q_a = {}
    for num, line in enumerate(line for line in f):
        if num % 2 = 0:
            question = line
        else:
            q_a[question] = line
```